# MetricNumeralExtensions.ToMetric is obsolete, use MetricNumeralFormats?

Tags: c#, .net, humanize, humanizer

We've upgraded Humanizer from 2.8.26 to 2.11.10 and now get the following warning:

```
'MetricNumeralExtensions.ToMetric(double, bool, bool, int?)' is obsolete: 'Please use overload with MetricNumeralFormats'
```

Are there any examples on how to use MetricNumeralFormats? What should I use to make it work?

This is our current code:

```cs
using System;
using Humanizer;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1234.ToMetric(false, true, 2));
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4IaMSv)

[Also asked on GitHub](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/issues/1111#issue-949469867)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how to use MetricNumeralFormats for your case:

```
using System;
using Humanizer;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // instead of
        Console.WriteLine(1234.ToMetric(false, true, 2));
        // do
        var decimals = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(1234.ToMetric(null, decimals));
    }
}
```

output

```
1.23k
1.23k
```

`null` here is the format your want to use

For example,

```
var decimals = 2;
var format = MetricNumeralFormats.WithSpace | MetricNumeralFormats.UseName;
Console.WriteLine(1234.ToMetric(format, decimals));
```

will output

```
1.23 kilo
```

source: [MetricNumeralTests](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/12cc40033da9a18a19d0da419a1d39ab9ae76dba/src/Humanizer.Tests.Shared/MetricNumeralTests.cs) and [MetricNumeralFormats](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/12cc40033da9a18a19d0da419a1d39ab9ae76dba/src/Humanizer/MetricNumeralFormats.cs)